# No evaluator set for filter null, using logback-spring.xml in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback

I am writing logback file for my spring boot application but facing this issue, found no solution on internet. It would be really helpful if someone can help.

**Logback.xml**

```
<appender class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender" name="INFO">
    <File>${log.dir}/default.log</File>
    <append>true</append>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${log.dir}/default.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>${log.default.maxFileSize}</maxFileSize>
        <maxHistory>${log.maxHistory}</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>${log.pattern}</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<appender class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender" name="ASYNC-INFO">
    <discardingThreshold>${async.discardingThreshold}
    </discardingThreshold>
    <queueSize>${async.queueSize}</queueSize>
    <neverBlock>${neverBlock}</neverBlock>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
        <OnMismatch>DENY</OnMismatch>
        <OnMatch>NEUTRAL</OnMatch>
    </filter>
    <appender-ref ref="INFO"/>
</appender>
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC-INFO"/>
</root>
```

**ERROR**

ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter@13fd2ccd - No evaluator set for filter null

**Note**
I don't have much idea about code.

**One More Question**

I have multiple logback.xml files based on environments like a stage, production, etc. How can I pass them while running a jar?

Tried java - jar jarfile.jar --spring.config.location=application.yml,logback-dev.xml

Comment: for profiles, you should set your profile and use `-P` in the java command to activate the profile of your choice (stage, production...)

Comment: Any other way to do so, like passing logback file in the parameter while running the jar similar to when we give the application.yml file?